# How to delete more than 50 tweets in 15 minutes per user?

Tags: twitter, twitter-oauth, twitter-api-v2

we are integrating an website to let users to delete tweets by authenticating their twitter account. It's working as per the twitter  rate limit.(Can delete 50 tweets in 15 minutes). I found some of site can delete more than 1000 tweets in 15 minutes For example [TweetDelete](https://tweetdelete.net/) site. What we should do to achieve the same?